# Renaming the bibliography page using BibTeX

Tags: bibliographies, naming

Is there a way to rename (or do away with the name of) the bibliography page that is output using BibTeX?  If so, is the name dependent on the bibliographystyle, or is it something inherent within the BibTeX functionality?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

This does not depend on BibTeX, but on the document class. The article class uses the `\refname` macro (which is defined as `References`) when typesetting the bibliography heading; the book and report class use `\bibname` (which is defined as `Bibliography`). So try to add e.g. the following to your preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Whatever floats your boat}
```

EDIT: Special bibliography packages may use a different mechanism.

Comment: @user19502 If you use `babel`, see Danie Els' answer. If that doesn't help, please ask a new question and include a MWE.

Comment: This works, but only when I add the new definition after \begin{document}.

Comment: This works for Biber as well, for those few users like me using biber.

Comment: Adding to what @Yoda said, I got this to work when I added this command right above \bibliographystyle{} which itself I had right above \bibliography{}

Answer (score 40):

Just be careful if you are using babel to setup a language. The `\captions<lang>` command overwrites everything. Rather use the following

```
\documentclass[afrikaans, english,%... Global language selection
              ]{book}
\usepackage{babel}%.................. Language setup
    \addto{\captionsafrikaans}{\renewcommand{\bibname}{Lys van Verwysings}}
    \addto{\captionsenglish}{\renewcommand{\bibname}{List of References}}
```

Comment: Nice answer! But note that answers should be self-contained and not refer to or relay on other answers (too much). Otherwise it might be confusing for the reader to read: answers with the same amount of votes are displayed in random order and in theory the other answer could be deleted by the author.

Answer (score 31):

```
Change bibliography heading
```

> You can change the heading of your bibliography by inserting a ERT
>   element 
>   (Insert→TeX) right before the bibliography with the following command: 
>   `\renewcommand\refname{New References Header}` or
>   `\renewcommand\bibname{New Bibliography Header}`, depending on whether you
>   use an article or a report/book class.

[source](http://wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/Tips#toc1)

I also tried with `\renewcommand\bibname{New Bibliography Header}` and it didn't work, but with `\renewcommand\refname{New References Header}` it did work.

Comment: Same here, only `\refname` works (using BibLaTeX though).

Answer (score 22):

Renaming the bibliography depends on whether you are using `babel` or not. Without `babel` it is simple

```
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
```

With babel it depends again on the language option. Assumed that you set `english` as language option, it will look like

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\addto{\extrasenglish}{%
  \renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
}
```

Comment: Was the first approach that worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: This saved my time!

Answer (score 19):

For BibLaTeX, set the option `title` of `\printbibliography`:

```
\printbibliography[title = {Whatever title you want to make}]
```

Comment: Welcome, you might want to mention that this only is valid for package `biblatex`.

Comment: Does not seem to work for empty titles `title = { }`. Do you know how to get that?

Answer (score 4):

Renew the `\bibsection`-command. For example:

`\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\subsection*{New title, typeset as un-numbered subsection.}}`

(Credits to http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4089, where I found the solution which worked for me.)

Comment: This won't work for all use cases, though.

Comment: Works with revtex