# Code to title the bibliography 'References' instead of Bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, naming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Renaming the bibliography page using BibTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12597/renaming-the-bibliography-page-using-bibtex)

I am writing an M.Sc thesis. I have problem trying to rename the bibliography as 'References'. I have tried quite a few tricks but they did not work. Some of the trick are

```
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
```

and also

```
\makeatletter
\def\thebibliography#1{\chapter*{REFERENCES\@mkboth
{REFERENCES}{REFERENCES}}\list
{[\arabic{enumi}]}{\settowidth\labelwidth{[#1]}\leftmargin\labelwidth
\advance\leftmargin\labelsep
\usecounter{enumi}}
\def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}
\sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000
\sfcode`\.=1000\relax}
\makeatother
```

The first code has no effect on the output while the second one changed my bibliography style. The bibliography was to be indent but it now appeared blocked after including the second code.

I also was a code to write 'chapter one' instead of 'chapter 1' meaning I want to write the chapter number in word instead of figures .

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you showed a complete minimal working example of your problem rather than just fragments. (e.g. it's important to know what document class you are using, and what package you are using for bibliography support: `natbib`, `biblatex`?

Answer (score 7):

use `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}}` or use the `babel`-macro ? `\addtocaptionsenglish{...}`

Comment: `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}}` worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> I also [want] a code to write 'chapter one' instead of 'chapter 1'
>   meaning I want to write the chapter number in word instead of figures
>   .

This can be solved by loading the [fmtcount](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fmtcount) package in your document's preamble and by providing the following instructions:

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\numberstring{chapter}} % for lowercase one, two, three, ...
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
```

It is also necessary to redefine the `\thesection` command, as otherwise you'd get strange-looking section headers that are numbered "two.1", "two.2", etc. If you want the text strings representing the chapter numbers start with an uppercase letter, just use the command `\Numberstring`.

You also wrote:

> I have problem trying to rename the bibliography as 'References'.

It's strange that the command `\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}` doesn't work for you, as that is indeed the recommended way to achieve your goal. Are you maybe loading some bibliography-related packages *after* executing this command? If so, try moving the command to a later stage of the preamble.