# How to set BibTeX bibliography title?

Tags: bibliographies, naming

Currently my bibliography says "Literatur" (german). But I want something completely different there. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Please check [Renaming the bibliography page using BibTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12597/2693) (especially the second answer, which deals with `babel`. If that solves your problem, we can close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: This is more or less my problem, yes. egreg has also given me a useable answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're using, say,

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
```

put the following in your preamble

```
\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand{\refname}{Whatever}}
```

if you're using the **article** class, or

```
\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand{\bibname}{Whatever}}
```

for the **book** or **report** classes. KoMa classes use the same commands: `\refname` for **scrartcl** and `\bibname` for **scrreprt** and **scrbook**.

Comment: Please note that if you are using [`authordate`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/authordate) as your bibliography style, the `\addto\captions<language>{\renewcommand{\refname}{Whatever}}` commands must be placed after `\usepackage{authordate1-4}`. This is because `authordate` contains a hardcoded redefinition of bibliography title as `\def\bibtitle{References}`. Just spent half an hour arguing with my editor.