# How can I add references without writing bibliography

Tags: cross-referencing

My chapter name is References. I want all my references under that heading. If I am using `bibliography` command then all are going under the heading Bibliography. Also I have tried using the `natbib` package, writing all the references inside a `.bib` file and using that one inside the reference chapter. But no results are there as outcome.

Comment: Hi and welcome, you can do `renewcommand{\bibname}{References}`, but there might be a better solution depending on what you are using.

Comment: Which document class do you use?

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the section your bibliography is printed into. Check https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36399/41739