# Changing heading of thebibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I used `\begin{thebibliography}` for my bib. I know bibtex is recommended but I finished my work so I would prefer to avoid changes.
The heading is "Bibliography" but I'd prefer to have "References".

I though to an issue with babel so I changed from:

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
```

to

```
\usepackage[american]{babel}
```

with no results.

I used also `\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}` but nothing changed.
My preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside, openright]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew,utf8,latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\bibliographystyle{harward}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! `\usepackage[ansinew,utf8,latin1]{inputenc}` is a mess. Stick to utf8. For the bibliography  title, try `\renewcommand\englishbibname{References}`.

Comment: See [How to set BibTeX bibliography title?(https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36399/124842) or [How to set BibTeX bibliography title?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36399/124842)

Comment: Is there really a bibliography style called `harward` (note the "w")?!