# How to change the text Bibliography to References in scrreprt

Tags: bibliographies, labels

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

.
.
.

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
\begin{thebibliography}{ZZ} 

\end{thebibliography}
```

What should I add to these lines?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36399/134574

Comment: But it doesn't work on scrreprt