# How to change bibliography title to Literature in article

Tags: bibliographies, titles

I need to change the heading of bibliography in `article` document class from References to Literature.

I have tried using :

```
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Literature}
```

(from this question [Renaming the bibliography page using BibTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12597/renaming-the-bibliography-page-using-bibtex) ) but this won't help.

My code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[polish, english]{babel}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\selectlanguage{english}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
...
...
\newpage
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: When using `babel` the process is slightly different, see [How to change the name of document elements like “Figure”, “Contents”, “Bibliography” etc.?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82993)

Comment: Using `\addto\captionsenglish{%
  \renewcommand{\refname}{Literature}%
}` worked :) you can post it as an answer.

Comment: Nah, we'll rather close as duplicate.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. ok :(