# Can't change the language of the title Bibliography

Tags: biblatex, babel, languages

I am writing my PhD thesis. The entire document is in Greek with exception of some words in English while the entire bibliography is in English. The issue that I have is that the title of my bibliography is "Bibliography" and I want to have "Αναφορές" or "Βιβλιογραφία". When I change the language I have for title the Greek word but all the references change in Greek words and symbols. How can I have in Greek the title of the bibliography but not the following references?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {/home/Petros/images/} }

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newlength{\drop}

\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib1.bib} 

\begin{document}

\foreignlanguage{english}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does  `\printbibliography[title=Αναφορές]` work?

Comment: Apologies. I thought you wanted an English title for the bibliography. @TorbjørnT's solution should work. However, you could also try adding the option `language=greek` with `biblatex`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What's the purpose of `\foreignlanguage{english}`? Try removing it.

Comment: Τhank you for your answers..but i didnt do it. If i erase \foreignlanguage{english} and write \printbibliography[title=Αναφορές],  i have the references in greek and the title Αναφορές. If i add only \printbibliography[title=Αναφορές] i have at the end of the references [τίτλε=Βιβλιογραφία]

Comment: i tried to include in the bibtex language= {english} or lagid = {english} pr hypnenation = {english} but didint work either

Comment: I may be well off here, but would using `\renewcommand{\bibname}{your title}` be a solution?  [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12597/renaming-the-bibliography-page-using-bibtex)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Do you want to add an answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B Doesn't seem like my suggestion worked.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I added an answer.

Answer (score 5):

A quick look into the manual of `babel` reveals:
`\foreignlanguage{<language>}{<text>}`

If you are using the correct commands, it works perfectly fine.

[image: petrosmourouzisBiblatexGreek]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newlength{\drop}

\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib} 

\begin{document}
To LaTeX (προφέρεται 'λάτεχ') είναι μια γλώσσα δημιουργίας εγγράφων συνδεδεμένο με το
σύστημα αυτόματης στοιχειοθεσίας TeX. Ο όρος LaTeX αναφέρεται μόνο στη γλώσσα στην οποία
είναι γραμμένα τα έγγραφα, όχι στον επεξεργαστή κειμένου που χρησιμοποιείται για να
γραφούν τα έγγραφα αυτά.
\cite{aristotle:physics}

\selectlanguage{english}
\printbibliography[title=\foreignlanguage{greek}{Αναφορές}]

\end{document}
```