# in bibliography i like to move the pp to next line

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, ieeetran

[image]

In bibliography page number is left in the end of the line how to move the pp to the next line ???

Using Bibtex and using IEEE style and also i like to change the title from bibliography to references

Comment: Do you use BibTeX or biblatex to generate the bibliography? If it's BibTeX, which bibliography style do you use?

Comment: The name of the header of the bibliography is determined by the document class. Which document class do you use? Also, I can find no bibliography style file named `IEEE.bst`; please advise on the argument of the `\bibliographystyle` instruction.

Comment: i use book document class \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

Comment: See the posting [Renaming the bibliography page using BibTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12597/5001) to address the question of how to change the bibliography header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make BibTeX insert a "tie" (unbreakable space) instead of an ordinary (breakable) space after "pp." when using the `IEEEtran` bibliography style, you could proceed with the following solution:

- Locate the file `IEEEtran.bst` in your TeX distribution, and make a copy of the file; name the copy, say, `IEEEtrantie.bst`. (Do *not* edit the file `IEEEtran.bst` directly.)
- Open the file `IEEEtrantie.bst` in a text editor of your choice, and locate the function `tie.or.space.prefix`.  It should look like this:

  ```
  FUNCTION {tie.or.space.prefix}
  { duplicate$ text.length$ #3 <
      { "~" }
      { " " }
    if$
    swap$
  }
  ```
- In this function, change `#3` to `#7`. That way, a tie rather than a space will be inserted between `pp.` and `33--50`.
- Save the file `IEEEtrantie.bst`, either in the directory where your main TeX file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter method, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution.
- Start using the new bibliography style by changing the instruction `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}` to `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtrantie}`. And, be sure to re-run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing!