# Rename bibliography title in Unicode

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I want to have non-English charachters in bibliography title. So I tried [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12597/renaming-the-bibliography-page-using-bibtex) solution.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\section{Preface}

This isn't supposed to be.\cite{DUMMY:1}

\newpage

\bibliography{biblist.bib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

%\renewcommand{\bibname}{Kaynakça}
\printbibliography[title = {\text{Kaynakça}}]

\end{document}
```

Both commented `\renewcommand{\bibname}{Kaynakça}` and  `\printbibliography[title = {\text{Kaynakça}}]` didn't work.

My Biblist.bib file:

```
@BOOK{DUMMY:1,
   title = {{B}ook {T}itle},
   publisher = {Publisher},
   author = {Smith, J.~M. and Jones, A.~B.},
   year = {2012},
   edition = {7th},
}

@ARTICLE{DUMMY:2,
   author = {Jones, A.~B. and Smith, J.~M.},
   title = {{A}rticle {T}itle},
   journal = {{J}ournal {T}itle},
   year = {2013},
   volume = {13},
   pages = {123-456},
   number = {52},
   month = {March},
   publisher = {Publisher}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seems to want to use `bibtex` with class `article`.

Please note that the command to rename the title of bibliography with class `article` is:

```
\renewcommand{\refname}{Kaynakça}
```

`\printbibliography` can you only use if you load `biblatex` and then better use `biber`...

With the following code

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{DUMMY:1,
   title = {{B}ook {T}itle},
   publisher = {Publisher},
   author = {Smith, J.~M. and Jones, A.~B.},
   year = {2012},
   edition = {7th},
}

@ARTICLE{DUMMY:2,
   author = {Jones, A.~B. and Smith, J.~M.},
   title = {{A}rticle {T}itle},
   journal = {{J}ournal {T}itle},
   year = {2013},
   volume = {13},
   pages = {123-456},
   number = {52},
   month = {March},
   publisher = {Publisher}
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}

\renewcommand{\refname}{Kaynakça} % for class article


\begin{document}

\section{Preface}

This isn't supposed to be.\cite{DUMMY:1}

\newpage

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{\jobname} % bibliography prints here

\end{document}
```

you get the wished result:

[image]