# Latex reads only \ref when trying to use \refname

Tags: bibliographies, titles

I'm using `\begin{thebibliography}` in my bachelor thesis. It works well, but however I need to change the title of the bibliography. I found the solution that says that it should be possible with `\renewcommand{\refname}{New Title}`.

However, when I'm trying to use it, for some reason Latex reads `\refname` as `\ref` and name is not readed as a command.

Hopefully the picture below helps to understand what I tried to say.

[image]

So, my question is: Why? Does `\refname` need some package? Or is there some trick that forces compiler to read the whole `\refname` command.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if both latex and your editor syntax colouring think that's `\ref` it presumably is. Check that you do not have an invisible control character between the `f` and the `n`

Comment: better than a picture would be a small complete document that shows the problem, with an error from that definition. Your example should only need to be a few lines long but should be complete so people can reproduce the error.

Comment: You might also take a look here, if you haven't already: [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12597/renaming-the-bibliography-page-using-bibtex)

Comment: Are you sure LaTeX is reading `\refname` as `\ref`, and not just your editor?  Which editor are you using?  How do you know that LaTeX is reading that as `\ref`?

Comment: Hi all and thank you for you replies! I'm using Overleaf and you were right, it was just my editor that reads it as \ref. There probably was some other error on my document, because I edited other parts of it and now that line started to work and it compiles right even though Overleaf still reads that \refname wrong. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @V.K. -- Since this has been definitively ascribed to Overleaf, you might submit it to them directly and suggest that they should fix it.