# How to change the references name in a book class document?

Tags: bibliographies, formatting, bibliographystyle

I want to change the name of the References section and no solution i found in this site works for me. e.g, no answer to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12597/renaming-the-bibliography-page-using-bibtex) question solves my problem. Here is the document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\includeonly{zebras}
\usepackage{graphicx,mathtools}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,graphicx,enumerate,color,amsthm}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{chapter1}
\section{section1}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{bibfilename}

\end{document}
```

I know very little about LaTeX and i don't know what some of these packages do, but i checked the problem still occurs in this reduced version. Any ideas of what is going wrong in here?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle unfortunately this has no effect for me.

Comment: `\addto\extrasbrazil{\renewcommand{\bibname}{...}}`

Comment: You have `\usepackage[brazil]{babel}` which will already have redefined `\bibname`  to something Portuguese, you should use the babel mechanisms to redefine that localised version

Comment: ooh @AlanMunn just got there first

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you, i'll search about the babel mechanisms.

Comment: but unfortunately @AlanMunn solution is not working either.

Comment: The solution definitely works. You need to add this line after you have loaded `babel`.  Delete your old `.aux` files and recompile.

Comment: And the question you link to has exactly this answer: [Renaming the bibliography page using BibTeX](//tex.stackexchange.com/a/306268) so I'm voting to close the question.

Comment: @AlanMunn you're right, i was probably inserting it before loading the babel package all along. thank you so much